# powershell: Multithreading to a Hash Table

Tags: multithreading, powershell, multidimensional-array

I'm having some trouble with using multithreading in powershell. I've tried creating a synced hash table and doing ForEach-Object -Parallel -ThrottleLimit 3 -AsJob{...} but this just gives me errors.

A sample of what I'm trying to do is:

```
$index = [System.Collections.Hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
Import-Csv -path .\csvfile.csv | ForEach-Object -Parallel -ThrottleLimit 3 -AsJob{
        $nameKey = $_.($FILE_HEADER) 
        $dirKey = $_.($DIR_HEADER)
        $extKey = $_.($EXTENSION_HEADER)
        $nameLetter = $nameKey.Substring(0,1) #Retrieves the very first character of the name for indexing

        #Confirm we are indexing into non-null array as we step through dimensions
        if($null -eq $index[$dirKey])
            {$index[$dirKey] = @{}}
        if($null -eq $index[$dirKey][$extKey])
            {$index[$dirKey][$extKey] = @{}}
        if($null -eq $index[$dirKey][$extKey][$nameLetter])
            {$index[$dirKey][$extKey][$nameLetter] = @{}}
        if($null -eq $index[$dirKey][$extKey][$nameLetter][$nameKey])
            {$index[$dirKey][$extKey][$nameLetter][$nameKey] = 0}

        $index[$dirKey][$extKey][$nameLetter][$nameKey]++
}
```

In the result I would have a 4d hash table where I can call $index[$dirKey][$extKey][$nameLetter][$nameKey] to get a counter representing the number of times this name was added.

I am doing this because this CSV is half a million lines long and simply building my hash table linearly takes two hours. The next stage where I go through these entries takes even longer.

What I am looking for is the ability to run through all the entries of the CSV once and build my index file using as many threads as I want. What is the best way to go about this? Also how do I determine the most sensible number of threads?

Comment: multithreading will not give you any edge here, in fact it will make all the process slower and more so because you're reading and writing the same structure this will be prone to failure

Comment: if you still want to give this a try, the immediate fix to your code is to add `$index = $using:index` at the top of the parallel scriptblock to pass the reference of the sync hash (`$index` is not defined in the context of the runspaces in your code)

Comment: same goes for `$FILE_HEADER`, `$DIR_HEADER` and so on. these variables __do not exist in the context of the runspaces__ you need to use `$using:` scope modifier when referring to locally defined variables

Comment: The header names are defined in the parent function so they should be available, but why would this cause the process to be slower? My thought was since I'm only increasing a simple int by 1 on each pass it should be faster if I devote more threads to it...

Comment: you can test it yourself I've already given the pointers on how to fix your code. Writing to a single structure from multiple threads is very slow and in this case, will not be thread safe, all those `@{}` being defined inside should also be synchronized and that will make everything even slower.

Comment: even with $index = $using:index I receive the same error:
"Cannot bind argument to parameter 'index' because it is null."

Comment: Aside from the other issues mentioned above, using the *StreamReader* class can improve on time cost. This also sounds pretty expensive. I've never had to load 1/2 mil. lines into a memory, would you have enough?

Comment: @TechnoNewbie Where is the file located? On a network share or on your local disk? I just tested it with a 700 MB test file / half a million records (and 80 columns) and without the multithreading approach. Took 24 seconds in PS 7.3 and 1 Min 7 seconds in PS 5.1 on my local NVME. `fyi:` reading a file from a network share with a streaming approach in PS can take a lot of time. You should copy it to your local disk first, if that's the case.